# Why don't show the image by using the $cordovaFile in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm a new Ionic developer. I have a problem to test the cordova file plugin.
I'm trying to show the image to store in local file system.
I can get the image object by using the $cordovaFile
But the image isn't showed in view.

controller.js

```
var fname = "001.jpg";
  $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory, fname)
      .then(function(obj) {
          $scope.img_url = obj.nativeURL;
          $scope.$apply();
      }, function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
```

template.html

```
<img ng-src="{{img_url}}"/>
```

Help me! Best regards.

Comment: Which kind of alerts/errors you see in console log?

Comment: I can't see any log. Only I confirmed to get the correct nativeUrl by using the alert window.

Answer (score 0):

You might need this code in the **config** section of your app:

```
.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
       $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|content|file|blob|data):/);
}])
```

In my apps I use the analogous `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist()` in order to allow links with data uri scheme or blobs.

Comment: can you please check my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366545/unable-to-display-images-from-persistent-storage-ionic